# Auto stretch bootstrap column if neighboring div is empty

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

**Tools:**

I have available the following tools: Bootstrap, .less

**Question:**

Is there a way to auto stretch a column if there is nothing in the neighboring column. Here is the html i'm wondering about:

```
<section class="document-viewer fadeIn">
    <div class="tb-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                stuff in here
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="something">
                    sometimes stuff in here, but not always
                </div>
                <div class="something">
                    sometimes stuff in here, but not always
                </div>
                <div class="something">
                    sometimes stuff in here, but not always
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</section>
```

**What i want**:

(see dotted green line)

[image]

bootstrap version 3

Comment: You might want to specify the version of Bootstrap, there were significant changes to the grid system between v3 and v4.

Comment: As long as `.col-md-3` is present it's going to reserve that space, regardless of there being content within or not.  What you would need to do is remove that column when it wasn't in use, and change `.col-md-9` to `.col` (for Bootstrap 4) or `.col-xs-12` (for 3.x)

Comment: Which Bootstrap version

Answer (score 0):

You can add class/id .column or .column1 .columnN with style:

```
.column {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: gray;
    border: 3px solid black;
  }
```

Adjust the height as you want to do and add that class to your HTML.

Comment: The OP seems to want to stretch the left-most columns *width* to extend the entire container space when `col-md-3` is empty.  How does a `min-height` value address the width of the object?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the auto column class:

```
<div class="col-md-auto">Content</div><div class="col col-lg-3"></div>
```

Comment: Please let me know how my suggestion is incorrect if you choose to downvote.